# Springboot: start a and stop programmatically a scheduled task

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I have two different tasks, let's call them A and B.

Task A should start immediately (t0) and stop after a fixed time (t1), task B should start after a fixed time (t1) and run until i stop the service.

Both task A and B should do something every x seconds (for convenience, print a string). I know that in Springboot i can achive that using this annotation:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 6000)
private void taskA(){
   print("A")
}
```

But i have no clue how to start and stop each tasks after the time window has passed.
I have made a simple scheme to help you understand better.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: how t0 and t1 are defined? do they depend on the start time of the system or some calendar date? if the second one, you can describe almost anything using cron expression.

Comment: t0 = 1h, t1 = until i stop the service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can schedule a task programatically via `org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler`.

e.g.

```java
    @Autowired
    private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;

    void scheduleTask(){
        final int xSeconds = 2000;
        PeriodicTrigger periodicTrigger = new PeriodicTrigger(xSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        taskScheduler.schedule(
                () -> System.out.println("task B"),
                periodicTrigger
        );
    }
```

[This acticle](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler) can also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `fixedRate` with `initialDelay` annotation.
So taskB runs after an initial delay of 6100 ms.

A --------- B ----- A -------- B ----- A ------>
t(0)    t(5900) t(6000)    t(1900) t(12000)

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 6000)
private void taskA(){
   System.out.println("A");
}

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 6000, initialDelay = 5000)
private void taskB(){
   System.out.println("B");
}
```

Comment: Task A should stop after an hour of execution, then task B would start running until i stop it

Answer (score 1):

The `@Scheduled` annotation is for stuff that runs forever.
Consider `TaskScheduler` for the task that must stop and
`@Scheduled` for the task that should run until you stop the service.

Here is some code:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Blam
implements
    Runnable
{
    private int count = 0;
    private ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = null;
    private final TaskScheduler taskScheduler;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if (count < 6)
        {
            System.out.printf("%d: blam.taskA\n", count);
            ++count;
        }
        else
        {
            scheduledFuture.cancel(true);
        }
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct()
    {
        scheduledFuture = taskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this, 1000);
    }
}

@Component
public class Kapow
{
    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 6000, fixedDelay = 1000)
    public void taskB()
    {
        System.out.println("Kapow.taskB");
    }
}
```

`@RequiredArgsConstructor` is a Lombok annotation,
I highly recommend using Lombok.
If you don't use Lombok,
just inject the `TashScheduler` however you choose.